# Problems with css file in dompdf

Tags: css

I will use a css File, but it works not. Errot Message Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'stylesheet' (T_STRING) in /playground/test.php on line 8

What is wrong in:

```
<?php
require_once("/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
$name =  $_POST['name'];


$html =
"<head>".
"<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/vrmd_telefax.css" />".
"</head>".
  "<html><body>"..
  "Hallo $name</p>".
"<logo1><img src="img/logo_small.png"></logo1>".
"<div id="box0">Anschrift</div>".
"<div id="box1">Firma<br>Anrede Vorname Nachname<br>Straße Hn<br><br>PLZ Ort<br>Land</div>".
"<div id="box2">Datum:<br>Seite:<br>Kundennummer:</div>".
"<div id="box2a">04.10.2014<br>1 von 1<br>12345</div>".
"<subject>Betreff</subject>".
"<content>Hier der Text</content>".
"<footer>Hier die Unternehmens Pflichtangaben</footer>".
"<marker1><hr style="width:20px; color:black; height:1px; margin-left:0; text-align:left;"></marker1>".
"<marker2><hr style="width:30px; color:black; height:1px; margin-left:0; text-align:left;"></marker2>".
"<marker3><hr style="width:20px; color:black; height:1px; margin-left:0; text-align:left;"></marker3>".
"</body></html>";

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
#$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");
$pdf = $dompdf->output();
file_put_contents("file.pdf", $pdf);
?>
```

Comment: `rel="stylesheet"` should be `rel='stylesheet'` and so on

Comment: nice :-) it works !!

Comment: Btw, you have 2 dots in this line: `"<html><body>"..`